# WebUI-Popover didn't work inside while loop in a table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to create a popover using https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover. Here's my scenario whenever I click the calendar button inside my data table it will appear the popover shows the date and time of the said data in Mysql Database. But my code doesn't work. Here's my interface:

[image]

```
<table class="table table-condensed tablehead table-sortable table-hover" style="width:99%">
    <tr>
        <thead>
        <th>Transmittal #</th>
        <th>Transmittal Date</th>
        <th>Sender Name</th>
        <th>Receiver Name</th>
        <th>Invoice #</th>
        <th>Document Type</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        </thead>
    </tr>

    if($_SESSION['userrole'] == 2){
            $qry = "SELECT en.`transid`, en.`transdate`, 
                CONCAT(userlist.lname, ', ', userlist.fname, ' ', userlist.mname) AS sender_name, 
                CONCAT(userlist1.lname, ', ', userlist1.`fname`, ' ', userlist1.`mname`) AS receiver_name,
                en.`document_number`, doctype.`document_type`, vendor.`vendor_name`, stat.status_name,
                en.date_process, en.status_id 
                FROM `tbl_encode_transmittal` en 
                LEFT JOIN `tbl_acknowledgetransmittal` acknowledge ON en.`transid` = acknowledge.`transid`
                LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist ON userlist.userid = en.sender_id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist1 ON userlist1.userid = en.`receiver_id`
                LEFT JOIN `tbl_doctype` doctype ON doctype.`doc_id` = en.`doctype_id`
                LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor vendor ON vendor.`vendor_id` =  en.vendor_id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_status stat ON stat.status_id = en.status_id
                WHERE en.`sender_id` =  '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'
                ORDER BY en.status_id";

            $res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<tbody id=\"myTable\">";
                    echo "<td><h6>" . $row['transid'] . "</h6></td>";
                    echo "<td><h6>" . date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['transdate'])) . "</h6></td>";
                    echo "<td><h6>" . $row['sender_name'] . "</h6></td>";
                    echo "<td><h6>" . $row['receiver_name'] . "</h6></td>";
                    echo "<td><h6>" . $row['document_number'] . "</h6></td>";
                    echo "<td><h6>" . $row['document_type'] . "</h6></td>";
                    echo "<td width=\"200\"><h6>" . $row['vendor_name'] . "</h6></td>";

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    /////////           Pending Button Status       //////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    if($row['status_name'] == 'Pending'){
                        echo "<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary disabled\"><i class=\"fa fa-history fa-lg\"> ".$row['status_name']."</i></button></td>";
                    }

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    /////////         Acknowledge Button Status     //////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    elseif($row['status_name'] == 'Acknowledge'){?>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success disabled"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg"><?php echo" " . $row['status_name']; ?></i></button> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link show-pop left-bottom" data-placement="left-bottom" data-content="<?php echo $row['date_process']; ?>" id="click-acknowledge"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
                        </td>

                    <?php }

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    /////////        On-Process Button Status       //////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    else if($row['status_name'] == 'On-Process'){?>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg"><?php echo" " . $row['status_name']; ?></i></button> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link show-pop left-bottom" data-placement="left-bottom" data-content="<?php echo $row['date_process']; ?>" id="click-acknowledge"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></td>
                    <?php }

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    /////////        Incomplete Button Status       //////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    else if($row['status_name'] == 'Incomplete'){?>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger disabled"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-lg"><?php echo" " . $row['status_name'];?></i></button> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link show-pop left-bottom" data-placement="left-bottom" data-content="<?php echo $row['date_process']; ?>" id="click-acknowledge"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></td>

                    <?php }

            }
        }

    ?>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there any popover event do you recommend aside the WebUI-Popover? Even the Twitter-Bootstrap Popover didn't work on my code.

Comment: Can you post your js code?